# What is the etymology of восемь and девять?

Tags: этимология

What is the etymology of восемь and девять?

Comment: Why _восемь_ and _девять_ only? All Russian numerals from _один_ to _десять_ share Proto-Indo-European roots with English _one_ to _ten_ and Latin _unus_ to _decem_ respectively. _Восемь_ and _девять_ are not exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to divine the connection when none of the equivalents I know in Romance, Greek, Germanic and Indo-Aryan, whose relationship can be seen, as with the other Slavic cardinals, when these two bear no resemblance at all. So perhaps you could enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: Michael you are just wrong, both cardinals has obvious analogies in other Slavic languages.

Comment: No, I'm not wrong. Read what I wrote. The relationship, to the language families I mentioned, of the  Slavic cardinals, other than 8 and 9, is clear. If you know the answer, why not tell me?

Comment: Восемь ~ осьмь ~ octo ~ ocht ~ eight - it is a root which literally shouts "Hey, I'm a PIE root". And you are wrong.

Comment: @shabunc We have PIE _*oktōu_ and Slavic _*osmь_. _o_ is _o_, _k_ → _s_ is [satəm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centum-satem_isogloss) palatalization, _t_ was still exist in Proto-Balto-Slavic (cf. Lithuanian aštuoni), but somehow disappeared later (OK, I probably just do not know enough to explain it). The question is what _m_ is.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov oh, OK, let's try to answer this then.

Comment: Right, that's fine. I'm not an etymologist or PIE expert, nor likely to think 'Oh it's a satem language, so that explains the c/s'. And if you, who clearly are more expert, can't answer for the m, how am I supposed to guess? And now for девять?

Comment: http://aldampost.narod.ru/index/0-6 may be this link will be helpful

Comment: @Rocketq the person who wrote THAT clearly knows nothing about Russian language deeper than one or two centuries ago. So nope, hardly useful. Unless one truly believes that Russians invented words for numbers yesterday.

Comment: @Michael девять from old slavonic devętĭ "nine" < *newn̥-ti- (Influenced by dékm̥t "ten")

Answer (score 5):

In the past (18 century and earlier) Russain peoples said "осемь", not "восемь."
They said "Осемнадцать", не "восемнадцать". Now do not speak. But retained the word "осьминог" ~ Octopus. "Осьминог", not "Восьминог".

Восемь ~ осьмь ~ octo

Answer (score 5):

Восемь comes from PIE ***o̯ectou***

Девять comes from PIE ***e̯neun***

en, n̥, em, m̥ -> ę (and later -> Russian я) change is common for Slavic, so regularly it should produce (accounting for the ti-suffix) *невять* rather than *девять*, but the influence of the word for ten, *десять* changed the initial consonant to d-.

Similarly the word for eight came under influence from the word for seven.

Answer (score 3):

Both words come from Indo-European roots.

It is quite easy to see it if you use Baltic/Germanic languages as proxy.

For example, Latvian/Lithuanian astoņi/aštuonì have roots in Proto-baltic aštō-, which apparently is very similar to Germanic -acht and comes down to the Indo-European oḱtṓ-. Considering things above the Old Church Slavonic osmĭ for "eight" fits beautifully into set. "os" just got "в" added at the front which is typical for Belarussian language and Ukrainian language (not sure if for the whole or just its dialects).